# Error while compiling cpp code: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, g++

I am currently learning C++ and was learning how to deal with multiple files when I came across this compiler error:
" In function `main':
bravo.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to`sum(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status "

The code i was building was:
**main function**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "add.h"
int main(){

int a,b;
std::cout<<"Give me two numbers to add: \n";
//std::cin>>a>>b;
std::cout<<"The sum of two numbers is "<< sum(10,5)<< std::endl; 
}
```

**header file**

```
#pragma once
int sum(int a, int b);
```

**Sum function**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "add.h"

int sum(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}
```

So where did i go wrong?
I tried checking the error on stack overflow but i wasn't able to implement the solution on my problem?
Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a linker error because you likely just tried to compile your main.cpp function. The linker can then not find the sum(int, int), since you do not compile the add.cpp function as well.

Assuming you are using g++, you can compile both files like this:

```
g++ main.cpp add.cpp
```

and it will work.